# Programmatically create tabs in TabControl

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a form containing a tabcontrol that I want to modify based on user input on a previous form.  I have created a tabcontrol named "TabControl" (creative, I know), and am attempting to add a tab for each value of the array "tabNames()".  When I debug the program, I enter the values into the array on the first form, and when the second form loads, I get nothing in my tabcontrol.  Any thoughts?

```
Public Sub frmContent_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  lblTitle.Text = frmiFormCreator.txtTitle.Text
  For i As Integer = 0 To frmiFormCreator.numberOfTabs
    Dim tabPage(frmiFormCreator.numberOfTabs) As TabPage
    tabPage(i).Text = frmiFormCreator.tabNames(i)
    TabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage(i))
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating the TabPage object:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To frmiFormCreator.numberOfTabs
  Dim newPage As New TabPage()
  newPage.Text = frmiFormCreator.tabNames(i)
  TabControl.TabPages.Add(newPage)
Next
```

Also, your code looks like it might be creating an extra tab.  Maybe you want this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To frmiFormCreator.numberOfTabs - 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  This was one of the problems I was having.  It also turned out that I hadn't declared my form load function properly, and it wasn't even firing.  As for the numberOfTabs - 1, I actually had it subtracting 1 in the declaration of the numberOfTabs variable.  I'd be happy to upvote this answer, as well as the answer by Nianios, but unfortunately, I'm brand new to the site and don't have the reputation required.  Thanks to both of you for your help!

Comment: Ok, I have enough reputation to upvote now, so I came back and did so on both suggestions, as they were both helpful.  Thanks guys!

Comment: @nherrmann Instead of subscribing to form events, it's usually easier to just override the `OnLoad` method.  Just make sure to let the `MyBase.OnLoad(e)` line do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Public Sub frmContent_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  
    lblTitle.Text = frmiFormCreator.txtTitle.Text
    For i As Integer = 0 To frmiFormCreator.numberOfTabs
        Dim tabPage As New TabPage(frmiFormCreator.tabNames(i))
        TabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage)
    Next
End Sub
```